# Treating diaper rash for a teething toddler

Tags: toddler, teething, diaper-rash

My 13 month old baby girl is teething. Her nose is leaking, she has red cheeks and super red  bum (rear-end). With urine and feces, it gets worse, and two spots become red flesh (like road rash) so it is getting worse everyday (not that bad, but not getting healed anyway).

So the question: What do you put on that to get it better? 
note : zirkofax do NOTHING... photo availible on request

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar problem and it took a long time to go away. Firstly, consult a doctor.
Our doctor suggested the anti-fungal cream Daktarin, but a type without hydrocortisone. Secondly, we made sure her bum was always clean and dry after peeing and pooping. Thirdly, we made sure she had as much time as possible without a nappy on, even though this was risky – the risk is worth it for her comfort (and we have no carpet, so it wasn't too bad).

The rash cleared up after 3 weeks of Daktarin, but there were a lot of unsuccessfully attempts to beat it before that.

Comment: We had a similar experience and used a "foot cream" suggested by our doctor along with letting him not wear a diaper for as long as possible. I also think letting him take longer baths helped.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, you are almost literally in the same situation my wife and I were in about a week ago. Over five days we

- applied Desitin Maximum Strength to the butt rash each diaper change,
- gave her an hour of diaper-free time in the morning, and
- gave her a bath at night with Aveeno Baby Soothing Baby Bath

It took a few more days after for the rash to go away completely. We switched the zinc cream back to regular Penaten cream (good for less severe rashes) for those days.

The rosy cheeks bit we're just trying a moisturizer for now, because if it is related to teething it sounds like there's not much that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

We've had luck with calendula cream.  Lots and lots of calendula cream.  If you're using wipes for cleaning the little bottom, maybe try just lukewarm wet washcloths for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

My 26 month old grandson is suffering with all the above symptoms today, and has been for 2 days now. It started with him coughing and throwing up during the night 2 weeks ago. That lasted 2 nights and stopped. He has been teething bad for several months, chewing on fists constantly.  He began throwing up again and having very lose stools 1 1/2 days ago. His cheeks are red (with no fever), rash on bottom that becomes very irritated and painful when he soils his diaper (unfortunately, he is not yet ready to potty train). l have tried everything on this rash with no luck.

He is taking meds for the lose stool and the pain from the rash. I am now placing padded potty training pants on him and using Johnson's baby powder with soothing aloe & vitamin e, and pure cornstarch.Then I place the diaper over the training pants. This is working, gently absorbs moisture to keep skin dry and soft. Even when he soils his pants and diaper, he is not experiecing the pain of a diaper irritating the skin!  So, it is necessary to check his bottom frequently for accidents and change as needed. It requires more work, but it is relieving the pain in his red bottom! Hopefully this will all clear up very soon!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your kid has no allergies related to coconuts, here's a natural remedy that works well for us:
http://homeremediesforlife.com/coconut-oil-for-diaper-rash/

Just normal coconut oil. Slather it on every change, after baths, etc. Cleared things up well for us.

The diaper free thing can help, but we always did it outside in the back yard where a mess would be easily handled. We also live in the hot desert so it was easier to ensure comfort while doing the diaper free thing.

Personally I have never heard of teething causing rashes, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

My daughter had a very bad case of diarrhea a few months back that had her bottom so raw it was weeping.  With none of the regular diaper creams helping, her doctor recommended Calmoseptine.  This is available in the incontinence section at the drugstore.  It is thick enough it actually sticks to the skin, so it can provide some protection even when the skin is already raw.  A couple of days on this cleared her right up.